A alguien le pasó esto al trabajar con angular y mapbox?
******* ERROR ****** ReferenceError: document is not defined    at Map (C:\Users\User\Documents\GPS\front\node_modules\mapbox-gl\dist\mapbox-gl.js:37:571763)
Al darle en inspeccionar me aparece esto en la consola:
browser-external:node:fs:9 Module "node:fs" has been externalized for browser compatibility. Cannot access "node:fs.promises" in client code. See https://vitejs.dev/guide/troubleshooting.html#module-externalized-for-browser-compatibility for more details. from.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'stat' of 'import_node_fs.promises' as it is undefined. at from.js:8:9
Realmente no sé que podría hacer en este caso ya que todo parece estar bien

Ojo con la pregunta, seguramente a ti te interesa saber cómo solucionar ese problema y no si a alguien le pasó o no.

Comparte el código para que te podamos ayudar.

Agregando y tal vez sea este el problema, recuerdo que en un tutorial donde usaban Mapbox comentaban que necesitas acceder a los elementos HTML y ya que mapbox-gl es una librería de JavaScript tenías que hacer uso de @ViewChild quedando algo así: @ViewChild('map') divMap!: ElementRef; y container: this.divMap.nativeElement mientras que en el HTML <div #map></div>
